# Atom in a box and collapse of the wave-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse

Suppose I have an atom trapped in an optically transparent box. I'm assuming the atom is bouncing off of the walls and not bonding, i.e. the center of mass of the atom experiences a square well. Now suppose that I surround this atom by a photographic film and I monitor the film to see when I see a dot at a particular location and of a particular color/frequency. I'm assuming that the dot is caused by the emission of a photon from the atom. Given a dot on the photographic film at position $\vec{x}$ and with a color of frequency $\omega$, what can I say about the quantum state of the atom?

Comment: Certainly, you can say that, at some event, the atom emitted a photon of a particular energy which interacted with the film at a particular position.  Thus, you know that shortly after that event, the atom had less energy than before.  Since it most likely took some time to develop the film and, since the box is transparent, I don't think you can say much more than that.

Comment: sebastianspiegel: you are talking about **unfalsifiable concept**. Whenever you show that a particle has definite characteristics, you will hear the answer: "that's because the wave function has just collapsed, but before ...".

Answer (score 1):

The comment by AlphaCentauri is to the point, but I will elaborate the points.

> Suppose I have an atom trapped in an optically transparent box

This is a macroscopic description. If the box is not in vacuum with only one atom, we stop here.

> I'm assuming the atom is bouncing off of the walls and not bonding, i.e. the center of mass of the atom experiences a square well. Now suppose that I surround this atom by a photographic film and I monitor the film to see when I see a dot at a particular location and of a particular color/frequency

As a classical atom it will bounce around the walls,  which means it will be interchanging kinetic energy with the walls. If the hit is recorded , it will lose some of its energy for the record and eventually come to rest, classically. The hits will be random, and the frequency in the thermal range, since it depletes the kinetic energy of the atom as a whole.

As a quantum mechanical problem a box that can have a film around it is too large, and the system "box with its ~10$^{23}$ molecules, a vacuum and one atom" will have long ago [decohered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence), i.e. the description reverts to the classical.

> I'm assuming that the dot is caused by the emission of a photon from the atom.

The photon will come from the kinetic energy of the atom, thermal.

> Given a dot on the photographic film at position x⃗  and with a color of frequency ω, what can I say about the quantum state of the atom?

Nothing, you will have been exploring the classical thermodynamic behavior of a single atom.

You might be interested to see that experiments are done that look at the quantum state of the atom, i.e. the orbitals, with very [sophisticated methods](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/may/23/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom).